# Java 11 does not set Java Environment Variable

Tags: java, environment-variables, java-11

usually when installing an updated JRE, the environment variables will be set so that running any java command in CMD will use the new version.

I've just installed JDK 11 which doesn't have a JRE equivalent - well it's in the JDK - but java commands are still being sent to JRE 8.

This is no problem for me, I can always change the environment vars myself and point to "C:\Program Files/java/jdk-11/bin/java.exe", but anyone who wants to use my program, which requires Java 11, will not have their variables set and it's a bit much to ask them to do so.

Why are they not being set on a standard Java 11 install? Am I being stupid?

Comment: *but anyone who wants to use my program, which requires Java 11* ... wouldn't it require them to be on Java11 to run your code anyway? I mean are you assuming here that code developed in Java 11 would work with Java 8 runtime?

Comment: @nullpointer I think that's the point. You'd have to ask users to install Java 11 _and_ ask them to fiddle with environment variables. imho the best solution is to bundle a JRE generated with jlink with the application.

Comment: @JornVernee agreed and I believe to ease that part out some work has been already in progress for tools like jlink to create applications with bundled JRE. But, that would still be long-term.

Comment: bundling the JRE seems like a total waste of time - I guess it keeps it platform independent and all that but I've just written a batch script that searches for the JDK 11 folder and runs from there. Keeps the program small!

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is still pushing 8 as the "end user" Java install. That's why it's the only one you can find on java.com. Newer versions of Java are designed either for back-end use on servers, or to be bundled with the application itself. The latter option is what you want.

Comment: I still need to find an authoritative source that clearly states that I can bundle a Java 11 JRE (created through `jlink`) with a non-GPL software. All license files talk about "unmodified" distribution. And the classpath extension is not clear as well as it apparently does not apply to all parts of the JDK

Comment: Do you know how long Java 8 will be the "end user" version?  I'd been pleasantly surprised that I hadn't had anyone report any Java 11 issues with my JavaFX program, despite the main version still being a Java 8 style "run anywhere" JAR file, but hadn't realized that is likely due to Java 8 still being the default for end users.

Comment: @CBusDeveloper Azul has a nice article about this (and a java 8 countdown clock): https://www.azul.com/think-moving-jdk-9-sometime-next-year-think/